# Minecraft forge 1.7.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

When start minecraft forge 1.7.2 it prints some text and an error message and then instantly closes. It shows this:

```
[18:56:44] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[18:56:44] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Using primary tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[18:56:44] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[18:56:44] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader version 7.2.211.1121 for Minecraft 1.7.2 loading
[18:56:44] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.8.0_31, running on Windows 8:x86:6.2, installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31
[18:56:44] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[18:56:44] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[18:56:45] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[18:56:45] [main/ERROR] [LaunchWrapper]: Unable to launch
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:117) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Please tell me how to fix this ):

Comment: Looks like something wrong with a mod trying to load.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's tech support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the clue (but to be fair you have no way to know why it's a problem):

`[18:56:44] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.8.0_31, running on Windows 8:x86:6.2, installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31`

Java 8 is still fairly new and it does not work properly with Minecraft yet. Downgrading to Java 7 should fix this crash. (When it was new Java 7 had the same problem with Minecraft too, but Java 7 has been fixed since then and works reliably.)